# Sobreposição da área clicável de um botão no conteúdo da página

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Talvez alguém possa me ajudar.

[image: print do problema]

O problema é que a área clicável do botão verde está sobrepondo os links das redes sociais de forma que o usuário não consegue clicar nestes.

Código:

```
<div class="fixed-bottom">
    <a href="https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=[numero_censurado]&text=Ol%C3%A1%2C+" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" target="_blank">
      <i class="fab fa-whatsapp fa-2x"></i>&nbsp;Atendimento
    </a></div>
```

Como faço para limitar a área clicável do botão ao tamanho do mesmo nessa situação? Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define um width nas propriedades do css .fixed-button ou alterado seu padrão de visualização para display-inline. Isto resolve.

```
fixed-button {
   display:inline-block
}
```

ou

```
fixed-button {
   width: 150px; // por exemplo, pois teria que saber o tamanho da imagem
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Leandro! Funcionou direitinho. :)